# Select records based off of an associated records count

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I have three models:

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  # fields: url

  has_one :visit
end

class Visit < ActiveRecord::Base
  # fields: total_visits
  belongs_to :picture
end

class VisitDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  #fields: ip_address
  has_many :visits
end
```

I want to write a query that selects all of the pictures that have the most views based on a time frame. For example, I want to retrieve all the top viewed pictures in the last week. Currently, I'm looping through all of the `VisitDetail` records created in the last week, month, etc. and then summing up each `VisitDetail` to `Visit` record.

```
hash = { }

VisitDetail.where("created_at >= ?").each do |record|
  if record.visit
     if hash.key? record.visit.picture_id
       hash[record.visit.picture_id] += 1
     else
       hash[record.visit.picture_id] = 1
     end
  end
end

# With my hash, I then order the hash appropriately and query
# for the pictures based on the key values in the hash which
# represent individual picture ids.
```

My question is, is there a more efficient way to do this? Is there some query I can write that won't be as exhaustive on the database?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `joins` between your tables, and conditionally select by the `created_at` field on your `visit_details` table. Then you get the size of the array returned by the query:

```
Picture.joins(:visit => :visit_details).where('visit_details.created_at > ?', some_date)
```

Comment: How would I order the pictures in descending order from most viewed to least viewed?

Comment: Yes, based on the number of visit_details for each picture.